# how to make flutter web drawer responsive according to different screen size?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm making an admin dashboard with a flutter web that has a drawer. but when I try to access it on the mobile, drawer it can't be responsive yet ... how do I access the drawer on the mobile in the form of an icon list?.

```
body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
             Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    DrawerHeader(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Image(
                          image: ExactAssetImage("images/image.png"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
                      title: Text('Partner'),
                      onTap: () {
                        _setPage(ClientPage());
                      },
                    ),
                    ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.multiline_chart),
                      title: Text('Proyek'),
                      onTap: () {
                        _setPage(ProyekPage());
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

this display drawer on a laptop
[image: drawer on laptop]

and this is display drawe on mobile[image: drawer on mobile]

there is no difference: '

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make responsive web on flutter web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57491784/make-responsive-web-on-flutter-web)

Comment: if I use that, I'm a little confused by how to implement it into the widget

Comment: Try this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_scaffold. I found it easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to determine the page's screen size and update the children widgets base from the parent's dimensions. Check this [similar Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662947) for the sample.